# Email Opt out field on Contact - usage

Tags: email, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage, gdpr, consent-management

We have the Email opt out field on Contact, lead, Person account

I am trying to find a documentation that specifically mentions the usage or this field.

With individual object, we can control finer details and this gets reflected when sending email using Lightning experience.
HOwever, I am not sure how is the Email opt Out field is being used?
Is it only for mass email?

I found this link. -https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_opting_out_considerations.htm&type=5

However this is more for Individual record and not for Contact level Email opt Out field.

If I check the Email privacy settings under Deliverability, I see the privacy settings does not use the Email opt Out field but only Individual record checkboxes.

Does anyone has any documentations around the Email opt out field?